# meteor-bootstrap-datetimepicker errors when landing on a route/template that already had one init'd on it

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, datetimepicker

Here is the package I'm using: https://github.com/tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker

I have a 'dashboard' template that gets a dtp init'd on it when it loads.  I do this in the `Template.dashboard.rendered` function.

I have tried using the `destroy()` function of the dtp but I keep `... of undefined` errors when I use it in the `Template.dashboard.destroyed` function.

The error, and my code, is below.

Error .......

```
Exception in defer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateFormat' of undefined
    at dataToOptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/tsega_bootstrap3-datetimepicker.js?3ee822b778b56b656aef2c57849bd1c71e98b58e:257:22)
    at init (http://localhost:3000/packages/tsega_bootstrap3-datetimepicker.js?3ee822b778b56b656aef2c57849bd1c71e98b58e:110:13)
    at new DateTimePicker (http://localhost:3000/packages/tsega_bootstrap3-datetimepicker.js?3ee822b778b56b656aef2c57849bd1c71e98b58e:1383:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/tsega_bootstrap3-datetimepicker.js?3ee822b778b56b656aef2c57849bd1c71e98b58e:1391:46)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:417:23)
    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4:170:17)
    at $.fn.datetimepicker (http://localhost:3000/packages/tsega_bootstrap3-datetimepicker.js?3ee822b778b56b656aef2c57849bd1c71e98b58e:1387:21)
    at http://localhost:3000/client/templates/views/dashboard/appointments_panel.js?e214cbf044fe31c31fe6ab3e7801ca895fa5b10d:45:26
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:945:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:430:45 debug.js:41
```

My template js code .......

```
Template.appointments_panel.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.defer(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
            minuteStepping: 15,
            sideBySide: true
        })
            .on('dp.change', function(e){
                _.extend(picker, {_startat: e.date._d})
                $('.btn-calendar').tooltip('destroy')
            })
            .on('dp.hide', function(e){
                $('.btn-calendar').tooltip({
                    placement : 'top',
                    title : moment(picker._startat).format('ll @ h:mm a')
                })
            })
    })
}
```

my template html ....

```
    <form role="form">
        <div class="list-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn datepicker">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-calendar"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                <input class="datepickerinput" type="hidden" />
            </span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="notes..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default btn-save" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button></span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `destroy()` function is kind of hidden, and not documented on the man pages here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

After I read a good chunk of the source code, I realized that to access the `destroy()` func, it appears on the `.data('DateTimePicker')` object.

I hope this helps someone avoid the last 2 days I've spent on this issue.

```
Template.appointments_panel.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.defer(function(){
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            minuteStepping: 15,
            sideBySide: true
        })
            .on('dp.change', function(e){
                _.extend(picker, {_startat: e.date._d})
                $('.btn-calendar').tooltip('destroy')
            })
            .on('dp.hide', function(e){
                $('.btn-calendar').tooltip({
                    placement : 'top',
                    title : moment(picker._startat).format('ll @ h:mm a')
                })
            })
    })
}

Template.appointments_panel.destroyed = function() {
    picker = {}
    $('.datepicker').data('DateTimePicker').destroy()
}
```